# JavaFX Any workaround for a FileChooser to localize the internal elements?

Tags: java

JavaFX : Any workaround for a FileChooser to localize the internal elements?

I was using Chinese Windows 7 but am want to have the FileChooser to display the button text in English. Any idea?

I know from the ground up it is not possible?, but Any workaround? thanks.

Comment: Thanks, But any Workaround ?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ricemery/FileChooserFx) might help